What is the proper way to brace initialize aggregate types in C++ and how to enforce it
I'm working with a std::set<unsigned> and I believe that using braced initialized I need to initialize it with
std::set<unsigned> x {{ 1, 2, 3 }};

Now if my set contains a single element with gcc I can use
std::set<unsigned> x {{ 1 }};

however in clang this throws a warning for braces around scalar initializer even though it's a single element aggregate. It requires
std::set<unsigned> x { 1 };

Is my understanding correct? If so how do I configure gcc version 12.2.0 to warn appropriately.

Did you enable -Wall, -Wextra and -pedantic-errors?

Yes, I have
-Werror -Wall -pedantic -pedantic-errors -Wextra -Wcast-align -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wctor-dtor-privacy -Wdisabled-optimization -Weffc++ -Wextra -Wfloat-equal -Winit-self -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wnoexcept -Wno-unused -Wno-unused-parameter -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -Wparentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wredundant-decls -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-conversion -Wsign-promo -Wstrict-null-sentinel -Wswitch-default -Wundef -Wuninitialized -Wunreachable-code -Wunused -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-braces -g -O3 -march=native --std=c++20

You don't have to use two sets of brackets unless you're also specifying a custom comparison function or allocator

A point about terminology: std::set is not an aggregate type. The question is about list initialization.

Related/dupe: GCC missing warning braces around initializer

Also Nested Aggregate-Initialization Rule
